# UserControl inheritance with generic DTO interface

Tags: c#, generics, dto

I have the following problem:

I would like to have the following objects:

- Several DTOs, e. g. for employees, customers etc.
- Several user controls, one (or more) for each DTO which displays the DTO content and provides modifications the user might have made back to the DTO.
- The base class of these user controls provides some default functionality.
- A standard button panel with CRUD operations that should work with all my user controls.

What I did so far is:

- I have an abstract base class for DTOs and several special DTO classes.
- I have standard functionality in my default button event handlers. As an example: The save button asks the user control for the current data (via DTO), passes data to some checking class, and if all checks passed, the data are stored in the database. To retrieve the data, there is a reference to the client object setted via constructor.
- I have a base class for my user controls. This is not abstract because I would like to have designer support. Therefore, this class provides access to/from its controls via virtual methods, based on the abstract base class for DTOs.
- I have a generic interface based on specific DTO types which defines data access with identical method names.
- Now I create a new user control, inheriting from my user control base class and implementing the generic interface for the suited DTO class. Therefore, the **BaseDTO GetData()** is overridden with the **new SpecialDTO GetData()** method.

And here is my problem:

- Within my event handler, the Client control is of my desired type, e. g. CustomerClientControl. But the invoked method is not **new CustomerDTO CustomerClientControl.GetData()** but the base default implementation **BaseDTO  BaseClientControl.GetData()**.

How can I get out of this? Thanks for any help or suggestions to make the whole construct a little more handsome.

Edit: Here is some code.

```
// in my "standard functionality"
BaseClient Client { get; } // or IClientDataAccess<BaseDTO>
void ButtonSave()
{
    var data = this.Client.GetData(); // in runtime, this.Client is CustomerClient
    // the following works, don't worry. :-)
    if (this.CheckLogic.CheckData(data))
    {
        this.DataAccess.SaveData(data);
    }
}

public interface IClientDataAccess<T> where T : BaseDTO
{ T GetData(); }

public BaseClient : UserControl, IClientDataAccess<BaseDTO>
{ 
    public virtual BaseDTO GetData() 
    { 
        return new BaseDTO(); // some stupid default
    }
}

public CustomerClient : BaseClient, IClientDataAccess<CustomerDTO>
{
    public new CustomerDTO GetData()
    {
        // CustomerDTO : BaseDTO
        return new CustomerDTO(this.CustomerNameTextbox);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you invoke the method?

Comment: @stuartd: Code sample see above. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change function signature when overriding.
It means you cannot have this transform `public BaseDTO GetData() -> public CustomerDTO GetData()`.
So you need to change CustomerClient to

```
public CustomerClient : BaseClient
{
    public override BaseDTO GetData()
    {
        // CustomerDTO : BaseDTO
        return new CustomerDTO(this.CustomerNameTextbox);
    }
}
```

or to look for another class design.